# Web Pages Ending with ..../

Tags: html, apache

I have a website running without a domain name (it is connected to using my public IP) on Apache. I have several pages (eg. /Chemistry/) and the default page is index.html so when MYIP/Chemistry/ is typed in, it goes to MYIP/Chemistry/index.html.

This is fine and all but I was wondering why sites like https://stackoverflow.com/questions don't need a / at the end. If I did MYIP/Chemistry it wouldn't work, but for sites like stackoverflow, they don't need a forward slash. So my question is why is this and how can I make it this way for my website? Thanks!

Comment: It has to do with `URL Rewriting`. The page we are looking at doesn't actually exist. (In the sense there is no .html file). The entire path is mapped down to a `controller` which responds with content.

Comment: Actually, specification for a static (file based) website works as follow. If file exist, respond with file. If file does not exist and path does not have extension, respond with 301, appending `/` if and only if a directory with that name exist. Repeat process.

Comment: You can observe this behavior in the `Network` pane of Developer tools.

Comment: Please do not add the solution to your question.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I didn't know it was not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve the same result by using rewriteUrl module in apache, it allows you to manipulate (rewrite) URLs :

First, you have to activate mod_rewrite:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Setting Up .htaccess file

create .htacces in route directory of your site

```
 sudo nano /var/www/html/.htaccess
```

and then add your rewrite rules and save:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/+$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

the above rule will remove all slashes from the end of any url

Comment: Are you using wamp ?